# "Save and copy changes to all public communities" only updates the location on the current site

Tags: bug, profile-page, location

When I try to update my location:

[image: Location field in profile]

and save changes for all communities:

[image: "Save and copy changes to all public communities"]

The location is saved only on the current site. Is this a bug?

Comment: Yes it's a bug, and old one, that was never fixed.